# String to float conversion and formatting

Tags: c++, qt, qtcore

Currently I have something like this

```
float a = SomeQString.toFloat(); //QString has 2.37
```

Now float is 2.3690000031..

What I want is 2.3700000000.. any suggestion on how i could do that ? Also why am i getting 2.369 instead of 2.37?

Comment: @MitchWheat: Rounding is precisely why the result is NOT 2.370000. It's rounded to the closest representable `float`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Has been asked and explained so many times.) It is not possible to get `2.37` in a `float`. It is not possible to get `2.37` in a `double`. It is not possible to get `2.37` in any IEEE-754 style binary floating-point format. `2.37` is not representable precisely in such binary floating-point formats.

Read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

One viable way to "obtain" `2.37` is actually to store that `2.369...` in a `float` (which is what you do already) and then round it to `2.37` at the time when you'll need to generate the decimal representation, i.e. at the time when you have to present/output the value to the user.

Comment: I do agree. Rounding of float number is mathematical.

Comment: I dont want to get 2.37 i want a 2.3700000 the conversion is messing up my values.Also thank you for rephrasing your answer

Comment: @MistyD: Well, note that it won't be `2.370000`. It will be `2.370000358...` or something like that. And it is quite possible that that `2.369...` is closer to your original `2.37` than the other alternative `2.370000358...`. Which is why `2.369...` was chosen. That makes sense actually.

Comment: `2.37f`, the `float` closest to 2.37, is `2.36999988555908203125` exactly. The next float after that is `2.3700001239776611328125`. If the OP is not satisfied by any of these values, the OP must use another type than `float`.

Comment: @Pascal Cuoq: Apparently the `toFloat` conversion algorithm loses some precision (not surprising). Note that it is still happens to be `2.36999...` and not the `2.370000...` expected by the OP.

Comment: Hmm, I do not understand this reply. My snippet works just fine. Can someone help with this for me what I am missing?

Comment: @PascalCuoq: probably a double-whammy problem. `2.370` is converted to float, then converted back to string using a bad rounding to `"2.369"`, then back to float where it becomes `2.3690000358...`

Comment: @Laszlo Papp: Your snippet does exactly what is suggested by the answer. It produces an imprecise value in `float` (not `2.37`) and then rounds it back to expected representation (`2.37`) during output.  It just so happened that the default output precision rounded it to `2.37`. If you increase the output precision, you will see that it is not really `2.37`.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main(void)
{
    std::string QString = "2.37";
    std::istringstream StrToFloat(QString );
    float floatVar;
    StrToFloat >> floatVar;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using Qt, this is the appropriate code for you:

```
#include <QString>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QDebug>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    QString floatString = "2.37";
    QTextStream floatTextStream(&floatString);
    float f;
    floatTextStream >> f;
    qDebug() << f;

    return 0;
}
```

Run the following command with gcc for instance, and Qt 5 (or something similar if you have a different scenario):

Command: `g++ -I/usr/include/qt -I/usr/include/qt/QtCore -lQt5Core -fPIC main.cpp && ./a.out`

Output: `2.37`

However, You do not need QString for doing this. See the code below which generates the output `2.37` as expected.

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string floatString = "2.37";
    istringstream floatStringStream(floatString);
    float f;
    floatStringStream >> f;
    cout << f;

    return 0;
}
```

Run the following command with gcc for instance (or something similar if you have a different scenario):

Command: `g++ main.cpp && ./a.out`

Output: `2.37`